# How can I dynamically create a multi-dimensional array with negative indexes?

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

In Javascript, I have a matrix with a variable number of rows and columns, which I wish to store in a multi-dimensional array.

The problem is that I need extra 3 columns and 3 extra rows with *negative* indexes in the matrix too. So the result for a 10x10 matrix should be a 13x13 array with indexes from -3 to 9.

I define the array with:

```
  var numberofcolumns = 10;
  var numberofrows = 10;
  var matrix = [];
  for (var x = -3; x < numberofcolumns; x++) {
    matrix[x] = [];
  }
```

Is this the right way to do this? Or is there a better way?

Comment: What do you `matrix.length` expect to be, 10 or 13? Do you need it at all? What about Array methods (which don't work for negative indizes), do you need them or do you want them to operate only on the "visible" part? If no, consider just using an object to make sure it's no usual array.

Comment: I updated my answer, check it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define the matrix as an object instead. You would lose some array functionality but you could still access `matrix[-3]` for example.

```
  var numberofcolumns = 10;
  var numberofrows = 10;
  var matrix = {};
  for (var x = -3; x < numberofcolumns; x++) {
    matrix[x] = [];
  }
  for (x in matrix) {
    console.log(matrix[x]);
  }
```

Or you could define your own class starting as an object or array and work from there. Here's something to get you started:

```
function Matrix() { };

Matrix.prototype.LBound = function()
{
    var n;
    for (i in this) {
        if (!isNaN(i) && (isNaN(n) || n > i))
            n = parseInt(i);
    }
    return n;
};

Matrix.prototype.UBound = function()
{
    var n;
    for (i in this) {
        if (!isNaN(i) && (isNaN(n) || n < i))
            n = parseInt(i);
    }
    return n;
};

Matrix.prototype.length = function()
{
    var length = this.UBound() - this.LBound();
    return isNaN(length) ? 0 : length+1;
};

Matrix.prototype.forEach = function(callback, indexes)
{
    if (!indexes) var indexes = [];
    for (var i = this.LBound(); i <= this.UBound() ; i++)
    {
        indexes[Math.max(indexes.length-1, 0)] = i;
        callback(this[i], indexes);
        if (this[i] instanceof Matrix)
        {
            var subIndexes = indexes.slice();
            subIndexes.push("");
            this[i].forEach(callback, subIndexes);
        }
    }
};

Matrix.prototype.val = function(newVal)
{
    if (newVal) 
    {
        this.value = newVal;
        return this;
    }
    else
    {
        return this.value;
    }
};
```

Then you'd create your matrix as such

```
var numberofcolumns = 10;
var numberofrows = 10;

var matrix = new Matrix();

for (var i = -3; i < numberofcolumns; i++) {
    matrix[i] = new Matrix();
        for (var j = -4; j < numberofrows; j++) {
            matrix[i][j] = new Matrix();
            matrix[i][j].val("test " + i + " " + j);
        }
}
```

And you can run some cool functions on it

```
console.log("Upper bound: " + matrix.LBound());
console.log("Lower bound: " + matrix.UBound());
console.log("Length: " + matrix.length());

matrix.forEach(function(item, index) 
    {
        if (item.val()) 
            console.log("Item " + index + " has the value \"" + item.val() + "\""); 
        else
            console.log("Item " + index + " contains " + item.length() + " items"); 
    });
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/uTVUP/

Answer (score 3):

While you can create attributes that are negative numbers, you lose some of Javascript's pseudo-array magic.  In particular, `matrix.length` will still be 10 even though it has 13 elements. And the code in general may be surprising to anyone reading it.

You might be better off defining an offset to get the value you need out of the array index and vice-versa:

```
var offset = 3
for (var x=-3; x<numberofcolumns; x++) {
   matrix[x+offset] = []
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I understand now why I got such funny results when trying to log the array with console.log().  I don't really like using an offset though, since the first 3 columns should be really outside the 'normal' matrix...

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Mark Reed's points about this being a unintuitive use of Array. I think a subclass is in order. You could follow the tutorial [here](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2292-Extending-JavaScript-Arrays-While-Keeping-Native-Bracket-Notation-Functionality.htm) to subclass Array, keep the native bracket notation, and override methods like length() so they give sensible values. Subclassing would have the added advantage of making it clear to those reading your code that something besides your everyday array is going on.

Comment: `length` is no method in JS, but a very special property of *native* `Array` instances. State of the art is that you can't subclass JS Arrays, you only can decorate instances.

Comment: The article I linked describes decorating instances, I was using loose language I suppose. You're right about length though, I had forgotten that.